# final cut pro x - 1440 x 1080 prevent video stretched to fill in timeline

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I have created a FCPx project that is by default 1920 x 1080 however i have some video sources that are 1440 x 1080 the problem becomes when i import the video into the timeline and it stretches the 1440 to 1920 distorting it.

it's similar to this example

but even in this video it doesn't seem to fix the issue of the video being stretched.

how do i prevent such a thing in FCPx it does seem to not stretch it if the video isn't 1080..

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test for you and Larry is right ... Normally if the footage or file was anything other than 1440x1080, all you would need to do it set your Spatial Conform to none. However, in this instance FCPX is forcing a size based on the magic 1440 number. To correct this, select your clip and click the drill down triangle under scale in transform. Change just the X: scale to 75% because 1440 is 75% of 1920. That should do it!

Comment: Awesome! Keep up the editing!

Comment: I was about to post mentioning the Spatial Conform.  I couldn't get it to automatically set the 1440 video back to its original size, without this workaround though.  I was wondering why...

Comment: It is just that magic number. It works with every other dimension though (Larry Jordan said something similar, too, in the video posted above).